# Filtering dataset by values and replacing with values in other dataset in R

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I have two datasets like this:

```
>data1
id  l_eng   l_ups
1   6385    239
2   680     0
3   3165    0
4   17941   440
5   135     25
6   151     96
7   102188  84
8   440     65
9   6613    408

>data2
id  l_ups
1   237
2   549 
3   100
4   444
5   28
6   101
7   229
8   92
9   47
```

I want to filterout the values from data1 where `l_ups==0` and replace them with values in data2 using id as lookup value in r.

Final output should look like this:

```
id  l_eng   l_ups
1   6385    239
2   680     549
3   3165    100
4   17941   440
5   135     25
6   151     96
7   102188  84
8   440     65
9   6613    408
```

I tried the below code but no luck

```
if(data1[,3]==0)
{
filter(data1, last_90_uploads == 0) %>%
merge(data_2, by.x = c("id", "l_ups"),
    by.y = c("id", "l_ups")) %>%
select(-l_ups)
}
```

I am not able to get this by `if` statement as it will take only one value as logical condition. But, what if I have more than one value as logical statement?
like this:

```
>if(data1[,3]==0)
TRUE TRUE
```

Edit: 
I want to filter the values with a condition and replace them with values in another dataset. Hence, this question is not similar to the one suggested as repetitive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to filter. `filter` is an operation that returns a data set where rows might have been removed.

You are looking for a "conditional update" operation (in terms of a databases). You are already using dplyr, so try a join operation instead of match:

```
left_join(data1, data2, by='id') %>%
  mutate(l_ups = ifelse(!is.na(l_ups.x) || l_ups.x == 0, l_ups.y, l_ups.x))
```

By using a join operation rather than the direct subsetting comparison as @markus suggested, you ensure that you only compare values with same ids. If one of your data frames happens to miss a row, the direct subsetting comparison will fail.
By using a *`left_join`* rather than `inner_join` also ensures that if `data2` is missing an id, the corresponding id will not be removed from `data1`.

Comment: Upvote for the explanation, but [this is a solved problem on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52890385/9406040).

Comment: @MrGumble Hi! Thanks for the code and explanation.
Tried your code. Its working fine but it is also merging the column of l_ups.y into the dataset after joining.

Comment: @LAXMINARASIMHAACHARYA The join operations appends columns. Try examining why you get two, and then see if you can remove one of them.